# docker-compose pull images used FROM

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web_app:
    container_name: web-app
    build:
      context: ./web_app
    ports:
      - 1234:1234
```

./web_app/Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.pkg.github.com/my_app/web_app/web_app:latest as builder

RUN npm run build


FROM nginx

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 1234

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I'm having issues with the cache layer. When my `builder` image is updated, `docker-compose` doesn't pull it. Neither does `docker-compose build web_app`. I've been having to delete the image manually. Is there a better way?

Comment: Try using --pull when running docker-compose build. That should force an image pull.

Comment: !!! that was not obvious in the docs. It works! Thank you